# Failed to load ApplicationContext (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to test my application following samples on the Spring website.

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4")
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

And this is the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ProductControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testHomePage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

I get the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Any idea what may be causing this? I don't have any specific configuration files, only the a security configuration and a webconfig.

Webconfig:

```
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**", "/css/**", "/fragments/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/", "classpath:/static/css/", "classpath:/fragments/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the root cause/stacktrace of the `IllegalStateException`. The cause is in the very first exception occured, ISE is the result of chaining of multiple exceptions.

Comment: @Antot Updated main post

Comment: Looks like you need to add `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api` to dependencies list.

Comment: Sounds like you might be running on JDK 9 or higher? Is that intentional, or is switching to JDK 8 an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

The following line in the output:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

Tells us that the class `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException` is not found.

As @Antot mentionned, adding the following dependency to your graddle should fix the issue:

```
compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
```

For those using Maven, use the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```